# How I use onClick in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in jquery and I don't know very much about it but I have been trying to generate Excel and PDF from HTML using jquery. For that I use following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Assignment to generate excel</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Contents/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
    <script src="~/tableExport/tableExport.js"></script> <!-- @*Main file which does export feature *@   -->
    <script src="~/tableExport/jquery.base64.js"></script> <!-- @*Main file which does convert the content to base64  *@ -->  
    <script src="~/tableExport/html2canvas.js"></script> <!-- @*Main file which does export to image feature *@ -->  
    <script src="~/tableExport/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script> <!-- @*Main file which does  convert the content to base64 for pdf *@ -->  
    <script src="~/tableExport/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script> <!-- @*Main file which does export feature for pdf *@ -->  
    <script src="~/tableExport/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script> <!-- @*Main file which does export feature for pdf *@ -->  
</head>
<body>
    <table id="activity" border="1" width="50%" >
            <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>%ge</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Chinna</td>
            <td>1,363,480,000</td>
            <td>March 24, 2014</td>
            <td>19.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>1,241,900,000</td>
            <td>March 24, 2014</td>
            <td>17.4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>United States</td>
            <td>317,746,000</td>
            <td>March 24, 2014</td>
            <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Indonesia</td>
            <td>249,866,000</td>
            <td>July 1, 2013</td>
            <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Brazil</td>
            <td>201,032,714</td>
            <td>July 1, 2013</td>
            <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>

    </table>  


    onClick ="$('#activity').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});"

<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#exportexcel').bind('click', function (e) {             
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'excel', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exportpdf').bind('click', function (e) {             
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'pdf', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exportimage').bind('click', function (e) {  
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'png', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exportcsv').bind('click', function (e) {  
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'csv', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exportppt').bind('click', function (e) {  
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'powerpoint', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exportxml').bind('click', function (e) {  
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'xml', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exportword').bind('click', function (e) {  
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'doc', escape: 'false' });  
        });  
        $('#exporttxt').bind('click', function (e) {  
            $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'txt', escape: 'false' });  
        });  

    });  
</script>  


</body>
</html>
```

But when I run this code in browser then I get following output

[image]

I don't have idea how to use onClick event on this case so when I click on export excel or export PDF button I generate this files.

If anybody have idea about it then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` is a HTML attribute that needs to go with an element's tag, like `border` or `id` on your `table` tag. When the element that it is applied to is clicked, the code inside it runs.

To achieve what you want, you need to add a button and put the `onclick` attribute on that button, like this:

```
<button onclick="$('#activity').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">Export</button>
```

This method produces output which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

---

The other way to do this (and the way it would usually be done) is using jQuery's `on` function inside a `script` tag. To do this, put the following at the bottom of your `$(document).ready` callback:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $('#activity').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});
});
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to show him how to do it with `$("button").on("click", ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply I have added onclick="$('#activity').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">Export</button> this line of code but when i click on export button get                                                                                                  TypeError: $(...).tableExport is not a function this kind of error             so what would be possible way to resolve it.

Comment: how to do same stuff with this $("button").on("click",...)

Comment: @AbhijeetKale I've updated my answer with instructions on how to use `.on("click", ...)`. About your `tableExport is not a function` problem - do you get any error output in the console when you load your page?

Comment: Wow!!! great now I am able to get my desired output thank you very much I doesn't get any error once again thank you very much !!

Comment: @AbhijeetKale No problem! If my answer helped you, please remember to accept it.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 I need your help yesterday I had tried updated answer on chrome browser and on windows platform so it works but today I try it on Firefox and linux platform but it doesn't work and once again i get  tableExport is not a function problem so how to fix it. please help me I am stuck on that point .

Comment: I added this line <button onclick="$('#activity').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">Export</button>
and this line @end of $(document).ready   
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
     
        $("button").on("click", function() {
            $('#activity').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});
        });
  
  });   
</script>  
</body>
</html>

Comment: Have you included the `tableExport` module anywhere in your HTML using a `script` tag? `tableExport` is not built in to jQuery.

Comment: yes I have included it                                                                                                                  
    <script src="~/Contents/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
    <script src="~/tableExport/tableExport.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/tableExport/jquery.base64.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/tableExport/html2canvas.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/tableExport/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/tableExport/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>  
    <script src="~/tableExport/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>